# Sylius php - how to pass cart to twig template (Sylius Template Events)

Tags: php, sylius

The default context provider does not provide a cart object. There's only channelContext, currencyContext, localeContext and customerContext.

Is it possible to get cart in twig template using Sylius template events?

For example like this:

```yaml
sylius_ui:
    events:
        sylius.shop.layout.header.content:
            blocks:
                search:
                    enabled: true
                    template: "@App/Layout/Header/_search.html.twig"
                    priority: 10
                    context:
                        cart: how_to_pass_cart? # <-- How to pass cart
```

And using it in a template, for example:

```
{# @App/Layout/Header/_search.html.twig #}
{{ cart.itemsTotal }}
```

---

Right now, in the standard template, to display the cart, a render of the order controller is used with template substitution.

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/a0ad0d1e4c61ed8ec30bbb39e36184cb910736b2/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/views/Layout/Header/_cart.html.twig#L2

```
<div class="right aligned column">
    {{ render(url('sylius_shop_partial_cart_summary', {'template': '@SyliusShop/Cart/_widget.html.twig'})) }}
</div>
```

---

From my point of view this is not a very good solution.
Is there a way to get the cart via context parameter or ContextProvider in twig template?

Comment: Isn't the cart related to the channel? So getting it would be possible to get the cart through the ChannelContext.

Otherwise you might have be able to inject `@sylius.context.cart.session_and_channel_based`

Comment: @exepti0n Thanks for the quick response. Perhaps I'm missing something, but this config doesn't work:
`context: cart: "@sylius.context.cart.session_and_channel_based"`
In this situation, the cart is a string. Can you help with this?

Comment: @exepti0n About ChannelContext, there is no getCart method in ChannelInterface. [ChannelInterface on github](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/a0ad0d1e4c61ed8ec30bbb39e36184cb910736b2/src/Sylius/Component/Channel/Model/ChannelInterface.php). Same as in the CustomerContext.

Comment: It seems you won't be able to inject services with the `DefaultContextProvider`, so according to the [docs](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/customization/template.html#context-providers) you'll have to create a custom Context Provider so you can inject the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because we will not be able to inject services using the DefaultContextProvider, we can write our own ContextProvider.

Create a file `src/ContextProvider/CartContextProvider.php`:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\ContextProvider;

use Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\ContextProvider\ContextProviderInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Registry\TemplateBlock;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Context\CartContextInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\OrderInterface;

final class CartContextProvider implements ContextProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private CartContextInterface $cartContext
    ){}

    public function provide(array $templateContext, TemplateBlock $templateBlock): array
    {
        $templateContext['cart'] = $this->getCart();
        return $templateContext;
    }

    public function supports(TemplateBlock $templateBlock): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    private function getCart(): OrderInterface
    {
        return $this->cartContext->getCart();
    }
}
```

---

Register the new Context Provider as a service in the `config/services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
    # ...

    App\ContextProvider\CartContextProvider:
        arguments:
            - '@sylius.context.cart'
        tags:
            - { name: sylius.ui.template_event.context_provider }
```

---

After this, a cart will become available in any template. This can be checked in the twig template by calling the dump method. For example like this: `{{ dump() }}`

---

Or you can use the Twig Extension solution from [another answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77764758/23199685).

Comment: You might want to add a condition in the `supports` method because fetching the cart on every template block will degrade the performance.

Comment: I completely agree with you, this is also indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/customization/template.html#context-providers). In my particular case, I don't want the provider to know about the names of blocks or events. Perhaps an extension for this case would work better (as in another answer).

Comment: So my comment gave you the answer :) It would have been nice if you'd let me know so I could've turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Twig;

use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\OrderInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Context\CartContextInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

final class CartExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private CartContextInterface $cartContext;

    public function __construct(CartContextInterface $cartContext)
    {
        $this->cartContext = $cartContext;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_cart', [$this, 'getCart']),
        ];
    }

    public function getCart(): OrderInterface
    {
        return $this->cartContext->getCart();
    }
}
```

Then in the Twig template you can do `{% cart = get_cart() %}`